# Tutorial fails for AWS Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am currently working through [AWS's Node.js tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html), but am stymied at the deployment phase. When I try to upload the provided source bundle, the build fails and I get the following error:

`Unable to deploy application version: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles', OptionName: '/static'): Unknown configuration setting.`

Where does this error come from, and where can I look to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible you messed up the indention on the yaml?

Comment: I hadn't so much as looked at the source bundle, so unlikely.

Comment: The tutorial has you open the yaml file to edit it.

Comment: Not in the link that I posted.

Comment: "Open .ebextensions/options.config and change the values of the following settings:" - right in the link you posted. That's the yaml file i'm referring to.

Comment: In any case, the problem occurs prior to that step, during the deployment phase, before I reached that step or edited anything.

Answer (score 1):

"The current configuration assumes that you are using Amazon Linux AMI (pre-Amazon Linux 2), but the current default image is "Amazon Linux 2" and the static file parameter has changed."

Solution:

- edit .ebextensions/options.config file
- change:

```
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
```

to

```
   aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
```

reference: https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-node-express-sample/pull/21/files